# "анінс" замість "анонс" — гумор чи ні?

Tags: альтернативні-правописи

Зафікфоване у словниках слово "анонс" має французьке коріння і вимовляється відповідно до оригіналу (annonce) проте інколи, зокрема у українського журналіста Скрипіна, зустрічається варіант з "і" "Анінс". Це іронічно-гумористичний варіант на кшталт "Азіров" який висміює псевдоправило перекладу слів з російської шляхом заміни голосних на "і" чи така версія дійсно існує і є нормативною в деяких з варіантів правопису?

Answer (score 1):

Авжеж, це гумор, адже за [правописом](http://shkolyar.in.ua/cherguvannya) чергування `о`, `е` з `і` не відбувається у словах іншомовного походження.